# Insert character between the cursor position in edit text

Tags: android

My code is :

```
EditText edt
    
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    
        final String number = edt.getText().toString();
    
        int count = arg0.length();
        edt.setSelection(count);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        final String number = edt.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

I have a dialpad too. When I click a particular number in the dial pad, I need to add that number to the current cursor position. Also, when I press delete, I need to delete the number from the current cursor position.

Dialpad Image

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try the following code

```
int start =editText.getSelectionStart(); //this is to get the the cursor position
String s = "Some string";
editText.getText().insert(start, s); //this will get the text and insert the String s into   the current position
```

Here is the code to delete selected text from EditText

```
int start = t1.getSelectionStart();  //getting cursor starting position
int end = t1.getSelectionEnd();      //getting cursor ending position
String selectedStr = t1.getText().toString().substring(start, end);    //getting the selected Text
t1.setText(t1.getText().toString().replace(selectedStr, ""));    //replacing the selected text with empty String and setting it to EditText
```

Comment: @Aju Actually the deletion part is a hack which wont work always like, if you have text like: "Hello Hello Hello" and you want to delete just the middle 'Hello', it wont work.

Answer (score 3):

To insert:

```
    String dialled_nos = dialpad_text.getText().toString();
    String number = view.getTag().toString(); // 1,2....9,0
    int start = dialpad_text.getSelectionStart(); 
    dialled_nos = new StringBuilder(dialled_nos).insert(start, number).toString();
    dialpad_text.setText(dialled_nos);
    dialpad_text.setSelection(start+1); // cursor will move to new position
```

To remove:

```
    String dialled_nos = dialpad_text.getText().toString();
    int remove_index_position = dialpad_text.getSelectionStart()-1; 
    StringBuilder dialled_nos_builder = new StringBuilder(dialled_nos);
    if(remove_index_position>=0) {
        dialled_nos_builder.deleteCharAt(remove_index_position);
        dialpad_text.setText(dialled_nos_builder.toString()); 
        dialpad_text.setSelection(remove_index_position);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.Your remove method helped me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `OnClickListener` for your buttons. Inside there you need to update the text of the editor. For example for '5' button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String currentText = edt.getText();
    edt.setText(currentText + "5");
}
```

Comment: There is `getText()` & `setText()` in `EditText` class

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.getText().insert(editText.getSelectionStart(), text);
```

text being your actual string that you are looking to insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
etPnr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            etPnr.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            // TODO: If you want to do on the text, apply here

            if (start + count > etPnr.length())
                etPnr.setSelection(etPnr.length());
            else
                etPnr.setSelection(start + count);

            etPnr.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

You can try it

Answer (score 1):

**For Kotlin**:

```
editText.text.insert(editText.selectionStart, "Your Text Here")
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently use this solution:

```
public static void insertText(String text, EditText editText)
{
    int start = Math.max(editText.getSelectionStart(), 0);
    int end = Math.max(editText.getSelectionEnd(), 0);

    editText.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end), text, 0, text.length());
    try
    {
        editText.setSelection(start + 1);
    }
    catch (final IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {

    }
}
```