# How allow a specific character in Android numerical keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I'm developing an science app, and I have an EditText in wich I must enter an input numeric value, so the inputType is "number|numberSigned|numberDecimal", but the problem is when I want input a scientific notation number like "45.6E05", I can't input "E" character because of EditText's InputType.

How can to allow "E" character and only to show a numerical keyboard when the EditText is focused?

Comment: If you are asking how to show the System keyboard with numbers and letter `E`, then you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to show the numerical keyboard with an extra letter `E` on it, two ways around this are either make a button that inputs `E` to your edittext or to use the `android:digits` attribute like such:

```
android:digits="1234567890E."
```

Where all the characters in the brackets are the ones that you want the user to be able to input

To make do it using a button, in its `onClickListener` you just need to put the following code

```
edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + "E"
```

In the other hand if you want to insert the character in the position of the cursor then you should try this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661104/insert-character-between-the-cursor-position-in-edit-text))

```
int start =edittext.getSelectionStart();
String s = "E";
edittext.getText().insert(start, s);
```

Comment: android:digits="1234567890E." is exactly what I want!  It works perfect! Thank you!