# How to enable user input into android edittext in scientific notation

Tags: android, scientific-notation

I want to have an input that accepts numbers in scientific notation.  If you use any of the standard number formats, scientific notation.  For example

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/scientific_number" 
  android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" 
</EditText>
```

doesn't work.  The user can not enter the exponential portion of the scientific notation (IE 1.00E-19).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no built in method to show a numeric keyboard with an extra "E", which is quite baffling as it would be useful to many applications.

You have two options, one is you can design your own keyboard as described here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?automodule=blog&blogid=867&showentry=3460

Second, you can put a button that puts an "E" into your edit text (I preferred this method) or have the "E" be placed at the cursor.  The way to do this is described here:

[How allow a specific character in Android numerical keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635319/how-allow-a-specific-character-in-android-numerical-keyboard)